# Chrome or Firefox extension for video capture

Tags: javascript, video, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, video-capture

I'd like to write a Chrome or Firefox extension to capture video being displayed in a window or tab. I have in mind recording YouTubes or other full screen video for offline playback something like a DVR for online video. It's super easy to create an extension so my questions are:

1. How to do full screen/full window or tab capture in Javascript.
2. Can I put the Window offscreen sized to fit my device, a tablet say.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this mozilla labs addon:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozilla-labs-rainbow/?src=userprofile

> Mozilla Labs: Rainbow 0.5
>   by Mozilla Labs
>
> Record audio and video in the browser!

Comment: Thanks, this is a good lead. Unfortunately it was abandoned and has been superseded by WebRTC, which is mainly about connecting browsers for real time communication. However thanks for the link since it comes with code. It's pretty old but would be easy enough to upgrade an try in FF 28. WebRTC seems to be going in a different direction but I'll poke around more there too, see if they picked up the record option. I know you can record hangouts, but they aren't local. They go to YouTube.